# How to choose between preempt-rt & non-preempt-rt linux kernel for an IoT application?

Tags: linux-kernel, preempt-rt

I am working on an IoT project for which I have to decide between `linux kernel 4.8 preempt-rt` or `non-preempt-rt`. Quickly running the Linux RT benchmarking test:

`cd /usr/lib/rt-tests/ptest/rt_bmark.py`

which essentially runs

`cyclictest -S -p 99 -q -i 100 -d 20 -l 30000`

led to the following results:

1. For `preempt-rt`:

`6:12:51: Cyclictest completed. Actual execution time:0:01:38
Min: 3 us
Avg: 6.0 us
Max: 61 us
Max list: [12, 13, 15, 22, 22, 61]
PASS`

2. For `non-preempt-rt`:

`5:56:42: Cyclictest completed. Actual execution time:0:01:38
Min: 3 us
Avg: 5.0 us
Max: 2025 us
Max list: [11, 16, 22, 46, 207, 2025]
PASS`

The results have clearly tempted me to use the `prempt-rt` kernel as there is an overwhelming difference in Max Latency between the two.

I wanted to know if this is a sufficient benchmark criteria to decide between the two? Thanks in Advance!